Laravel scope: return record if another method returns true
There is a function like this in User model in Laravel
public function isOldUser(): bool
{
    return Cache::tags(['is-user-old'])->remember('user-' . $this->id . '-is-old', 60 * 60 * 24, function () {
        $hasOldTreatmentPlan = $this->treatmentplans->contains(function ($treatmentplan) {
            return $treatmentplan->created_at <= Carbon::today()->subMonths(3);
        });

        $hasOldVisit = $this->bookings->contains(function ($booking) {
            return $booking->booking_at <= Carbon::today()->subMonths(3) &&
                $booking->visit_type == BookingVisitTypeEnum::IN_PERSON->value &&
                $booking->visit?->exists() &&
                $booking->type == BookingTypeEnums::VISIT->value;
        });

        return $hasOldVisit && $hasOldTreatmentPlan;
    });
}

I need to have a scope for this
public function scopeIsOldUserFilter($query, bool $criteria = true)
{

}

I have tried but didn't work, like this
public function scopeIsOldUserFilter($query, bool $criteria = true)
{
    $query->where(function ($query) use ($criteria) {
        return $this->isOldUser() == $criteria;
    });
}

How to add scope which filters of a user is old or not.

A scope should only add constraints to the query, since the models have not yet been retrieved from the database.
The following is an example of how it could look like. It probably won't work immediately, since I'm not sure of how your relations are set up.
public function scopeIsOldUserFilter($query, bool $criteria = true)
{
    if ($criteria) {
        $query
            ->whereRelation('treatmentplans', 'created_at', '<=', Carbon::today()->subMonths(3))
            ->whereHas('bookings', function ($query) {
                $query
                    ->where('booking_at', '<=', Carbon::today()->subMonths(3))
                    ->where('visit_type', BookingVisitTypeEnum::IN_PERSON->value)
                    ->whereHas('visit')
                    ->where('type', BookingTypeEnums::VISIT->value);
            });
    } else {
        $query
            ->whereRelation('treatmentplans', 'created_at', '>', Carbon::today()->subMonths(3))
            ->orWhereDoesntHave('bookings', function ($query) {
                $query
                    ->where('booking_at', '<=', Carbon::today()->subMonths(3))
                    ->where('visit_type', BookingVisitTypeEnum::IN_PERSON->value)
                    ->whereHas('visit')
                    ->where('type', BookingTypeEnums::VISIT->value);
            });
    }
}


Because the query slow, I was going to use the Cache

Have you tried adding indices to the relation fields that are queried?

they have index in DB

Maybe you could try retrieving the ID's from the cache and use them to limit the query.
